# Bash - Replace ö å ä with o a a in all subfolders

Tags: bash, replace

I got a folder called data with folders containing names with å ä ö, and I need a script to replace all å ä ö with a a ö in those folder naames.
Example:
Before "Folder1 - ö - å"
After: "Folder1 - o - a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various `rename` commands exist. One of them uses the syntax

```
rename ö o *
```

The second one uses

```
rename s/ö/o/g *
```

Use `man rename` to find out which one your system has.

The first one can be implemented as a bash function:

```
Rename () { 
    if (($# < 3)); then
        echo Usage: Rename from to files... 1>&2;
        return 1;
    fi;
    from="$1";
    to="$2";
    shift 2;
    for file in "$@";
    do
        mv "$file" "${file/$from/$to}";
    done
}
```

Note that it replaces only the first occurrence of the substring. If you want to replace all the occurrences, use `${file//$form/$to}`.

### Beware!

There are several ways how to endcode ö in Unicode. Therefore, it can be utf-8 `c3 b6`, but also `6f cc 88`. If your filesystem uses unicode, you might have to try all the possibilities.